# Using regex in Google Sheets how do I remove everything within the <> characters, including the characters themselves?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

In my Google Sheet, I'm trying to delete the contents within any `< >` symbols, including the `'<'` '>'` symbols themselves.

For this example text: `<h3>AJ Sports</h3> has been in business for 30 years`

I want: `'AJ Sports has been in business for 30 years'`

I've been using this regex `formula =REGEXREPLACE(B2,"\s\<.*|\s\[.*","")` but it also deletes everything after the last `'>'`.

With this regex, the output is: `'AJ Sports'`

What do I need to add to only delete the desired portion and not the rest of the following text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use this pattern:

```regex
\<[^>]*\>
```

it will see any open bracket `<`, and match with the closest closing bracket `>`, including the contents.
More specifically, it will match with *any string that contains an opening bracket, and a matching closing bracket*.

#### Edit

[RegexR showcase](https://regexr.com/5nesq), explaining, and showing an example.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=regexreplace(B2, "<.*?>",)
```

and see if that works?

[image: Example]